# Selenium: How to prompt user input and use the input value?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a situation (during a selenium test), in which the user will receive a security code. The user must then input the security code before being allowed to continue.

I'm not too sure on how I can get the value the user inputted. I browsed around the [selenium docs](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_migrating_from_rc_to_webdriver.jsp#executing-javascript-doesn-t-return-anything) and came up with this. Unfortunately, it doesn't quite work.

```
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("window.promptResponse=prompt('Please enter the security code')");

    if(isAlertPresent()) {
        // switch to alert
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();

        // sleep to allow user to input text
        Thread.sleep(10000);

        // this doesn't seem to work 
        code = (String) js.executeScript("return window.promptResponse");

        alert.accept();
```

Can someone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Seems like something similar to CAPTCHA which is mostly there to avoid automation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have to accept and close the prompt first, before being able to store and use the value

```
    alert.accept();
    code = (String) js.executeScript("return window.promptResponse");
```