# Sending Text in Alerts in selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium

How to Handle JavaScript alert which contains text field such as username and password ? How to enter values in those fields ?

[image]

Comment: Tried `driver.switch_to_window()`?

Comment: Might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600003/selenium-how-to-prompt-user-input-and-use-the-input-value

Comment: I've updated my answer. Do have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is Selenium cannot identify the authentication popups. That is a limitation of Selenium as far as I know. You can overcome the issue with using java Robot actions to fill out the username and password.

```
public void handlePopup(){

  //create java robot for keyboard simulations
  Robot rb = new Robot();
  //First set the username value to the system clipboard
  StringSelection username = new StringSelection("your-user-name");
  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(username, null); 
  // Perform a control+v to paste the content into username field.           
  rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
  rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
  rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
  rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

  //tab to navigate to password field
  rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
  rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
  Thread.sleep(2000);

  //set the password value to the system clipboard
  StringSelection pwd = new StringSelection("your-password");
  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(pwd, null);

  // Perform a control+v to paste the content into password field. 
  rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
  rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
  rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
  rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

  //press enter to login
  rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
  rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Alert.html#authenticateUsing(org.openqa.selenium.security.Credentials)).

Comment: Yeah i'm aware of the authenticateUsing method. But still the method is tagged as @Beta. From my experience this method does not solve the problem in most of the cases. What i have posted is the way we have solved the issue in more than 10 automation projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
driver.switch_to.alert.authenticate('cheese', 'secretGouda')
```

You can check the doc for that on the console or from this [link](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.alert.Alert.authenticate).

```
>>> from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
>>> help(Alert.authenticate)
Help on method authenticate in module selenium.webdriver.common.alert:

authenticate(self, username, password) unbound selenium.webdriver.common.alert.Alert method
    Send the username / password to an Authenticated dialog (like with Basic HTTP Auth).
    Implicitly 'clicks ok'

    Usage::
    driver.switch_to.alert.authenticate('cheese', 'secretGouda')

    :Args:
     -username: string to be set in the username section of the dialog
     -password: string to be set in the password section of the dialog
```