# Print out users choice after input ... JavascriptExecutor

Tags: java, webdriver

How do i store user input and print it out using JavascriptExecutor? ... Below is what i have tried so far. The prompt box works fine and takes user input. but i need to get what the user input and store it in String, so that i can use it in my code.

```
JavascriptExecutor javascript = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    String ans = (String) javascript.executeScript("prompt('How do you want to SIGN UP?\\n\\n (1) FACEBOOK\\n (2) GOOGLE\\n (3) LOCALLY');");
//Object ans = javascript.executeScript("prompt('How do you want to SIGN UP?\\n\\n (1) FACEBOOK\\n (2) GOOGLE\\n (3) LOCALLY');");
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    //String answer = (String) ans;
    System.out.println(ans);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium: How to prompt user input and use the input value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600003/selenium-how-to-prompt-user-input-and-use-the-input-value)

Comment: @ArcticLord ....but am still getting "unexpected alert open" error.

Comment: `JavascriptExecutor javascript = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
   javascript.executeScript("window.promptResponse=prompt('How do you want to SIGN UP?\\n\\n (1) FACEBOOK\\n (2) GOOGLE\\n (3) LOCALLY');");
 
  Thread.sleep(5000);
  
  //Alert alert = null;
  //alert.accept();
  String answer = (String) javascript.executeScript("return window.promptResponse");

  //System.out.println(answer);`

Comment: have tried this code several times but all to no avail..... please any help. i dont think its a duplicate as the previous post is not printing out anything. i keep getting a null pointer exception if i attempt to print out because of the cast

Comment: @Joe why do you want to do it via JsExecutor? 
Usually, the use case would be to click on a button in the page, get the JS alert, type in text then get its value. But this should be **implemented in the actual page under test**, not by your Webdriver script. By synthetically creating the prompt, you're trying to add manual user intervention into an automated script - is this really what you want?
If you want to have control over what type of login to be executed, it can be done differently.

Comment: I suspect that you will find your answer in Q&A [Reading JavaScript variables using Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994393/reading-javascript-variables-using-selenium-webdriver)