# Selenium web driver : requirement to create a simple user prompt and retain input string

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium/Ecliipse to automate some webdriver UI tests. However, to kick some of the tests off I need help to do the following.
1) Open up a website in Firefox (I can do that bit)
2) Open up a user prompt that requests the user to enter in a string "Please enter in name"
3) Save the string to a variable
4) Close the prompt once the input text has been saved.
5) In the console System.out.println the string held in the variable to confirm its correctly saved.

I have tried a few things but have struggld to get the string to be attributed to the variable. Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: How about adding to your question what you have attempted so far?

Comment: This is what I'm attempting to run but I don't seem to be able to assign the input from the user to the string variable - prompt.

If (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {

Comment: This is what I'm attempting to run but I don't seem to be able to assign the input from the user to the string variable - prompt.
I'm opening up google and doing the following;

If (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {

JavascriptExecutor js = JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.promptReponse=prompt('please enter in string')");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,100000);
wait(); }
Alert alert = driver = driver.switchTo().alert();
String prompt = alert.getText();
alert.accept();
System.out.println("Text held is:" + prompt);

Comment: Have a look at this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600003/selenium-how-to-prompt-user-input-and-use-the-input-value...

Comment: I have looked at this comment but even when taking into account the suggestion the value is still not stored so I'm not sure why the input value not is stored or retrievable.